# Preencher ListView com um array

Tags: java, android

Tenho um Array List onde armazeno as disciplinas com as respectivas notas de um determinado aluno.

Este array possui apenas 2 atributos:

nomeDisciplina
valorNota

Gostaria de saber como faço para preencher um listview com todas as disciplinas e notas armazenadas neste array.

Obs: De modo que aparece em 2 colunas, a primeira com o cabeçalho DISCIPLINAS e a segunda com o cabeçalho NOTAS.

```
    ArrayList<Nota> listNotas = new ArrayList<>();

public ArrayList buscarNotas(String matricula, int etapa){

    try {
        SoapObject resposta = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);


            resposta.addProperty("Matricula", matricula);
            resposta.addProperty("Etapa", etapa);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(resposta);

        HttpTransportSE http = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        http.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        String resultado = envelope.getResponse().toString();

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(resultado);


        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++ ) {
            Nota nota = new Nota();
            JSONObject jsonObject =jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            nota.setDisciplina(jsonObject.getString("Materia"));
            nota.setNota(jsonObject.getString("VlrNota"));

            listNotas.add(i,nota);
        }
    }  catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SoapFault soapFault) {
        soapFault.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   return listNotas;

}
```

Comment: Poderia mostrar o que tem até o momento? Qual é a estrutura em que guarda as disciplina com notas do aluno ? Ajuda a ajudarmos você!

Comment: Coloquei o codigo, na verdade recebo estes dados de um web service e armazeno em um list.

Comment: Veja se o exemplo ajuda - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/153556/listview-com-duas-linhas

Comment: Amigo, estou com outro problema: Quando vou chamar este metodo em o outra classe ele está  retornando null.